# How can I debug node in VSCode with sudo in mac?

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-code

I want to debug node like this in terminal:

```
$sudo node app
```

But, in vscode, I don't know where I can configure it.

This is my launch.json. Nothing has helped,

[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBck7.png)

Comment: You can check docs of VSCode
[Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging)

Answer (score 6):

In order to run the command as sudo you have to launch VS code under sudo. Here's how you do that ...

1. Install "code" as a shell command if you haven't already by opening visual studio code regularly then opening the command palette (press F1) and type "Shell Command". This will bring up "Install 'code' command in PATH". More on that here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/setup#_mac-os-x
2. Run "sudo code" in your terminal, and you should see that when you run "node app" it'll be running under sudo.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with launch.json configuration that runs a script and uses port 80.

Answer (score 3):

First, create **attach process** config:

```
    {
        "name": "Attach to Process",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9222
    }
```

and **run it**.

Second, run node to debug like this.

```
sudo node --inspect=9222 app.js
```

Comment: If `node` is invoked through a program or script and you cannot provide `--inspect` directly, you can set the flag through the environment variable `NODE_OPTIONS`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  I'm trying to debug an app that connects to port 443 on a Mac.  In order to get around the problem I've been using I added the following to my package.json under scripts.

```
"debug": "sudo devtool server.js",
```

With this you can debug, just not as nice since you are using the chrome debugger verses the one in vscode.  You will need to have devtool from chrome installed for this to work.